# STDERR: Command line error: no such option: --force-yes

Tags: chef-infra, chef-solo

I'm trying to install **Java** using my Chef cookbook via **Kitchen** + **Vagrant**. The operating system is **CentOS 7.3**.

Because I had some conflicts with `filesystem-3.2-21.el7.x86_64` caused by the  Java version, I decided to force the installation.

So I decided to follow the next example from the [official chef documentation](https://docs.chef.io/resource_package.html):

> Install a package with options
>
> ```
> package 'debian-archive-keyring' do
>   action :install
>   options '--force-yes'
> end
> ```

I converted it to:

```
package "bf-sun-java" do
  version node['java_version']
  action :install
  options '--force-yes'
end
```

but I got the following error:

> STDERR: Command line error: no such option: `--force-yes`

Why is `--force-yes` mentioned in that example if Chef doesn't recognize it?

Comment: @peterh , and this is the reason why you down voted a question on this community?

Comment: `peterh` downvoted this question because he didn't like my username. He commented about it, but then he removed his comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The option `--force-yes` is an option for `apt` package manager. The `options` option in package resource only allows you to pass options that the package manager of the OS understand. For example in Centos I could write `options '--setopt=timeout=360'`, which is an option for `yum` and it works.

Also, take a look at what does `--force-yes` actually do in `apt` man page.

Installing and maintaining Java with Chef might be sometimes painful, so I'd recommend using the [Java cookbook](https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/java), which works like a charm.

Comment: I supposed that the `options` values are from Chef (wrappers over the native commands). Now, it makes sense.